# How to reload the screen in flutter on alert dialog button press?

Tags: flutter, setstate

I'm making an app that shows images from a subreddit and I want to change these images based on the subreddit names entered through the alert dialog. I have implemented everything as follows but when I set the state, the images are not showing. How to fix this? Here is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:memes/screens/memes_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    )
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  final TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  String subs = "memes";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 254, 241), //Color(0xffdedede),

      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Memes"), backgroundColor: Color(0xff008b00)),

      body: MemesScreen(subreddits: subs),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),

        backgroundColor: Color(0xff008b00),

        onPressed: (){
          _showDialog();
        },
      ),
    );
  }


  void _showDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(

          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 254, 241),

          title: Text("Enter subreddits"),

          content: TextField(
            controller: textEditingController,
          ),
          
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            TextButton(
              child: new Text("Close", style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff008b00))),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),

            TextButton(
              child: new Text("Get", style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff008b00))),
              onPressed: () {
                String newSubs = textEditingController.text;
                setState(() {
                  subs = newSubs;
                });
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The string `subs` is passed to the `MemesScreen` that shows an image. If I change this `subs` value on a button press in `_showDialog` method and set the state, the screen is not reloading. How to fix this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap MemesScreen(subreddits: subs) INTO ValueListenableBuilder(). Then Put String subs variable in globals.dart page so that it can be changed on setState.
Edit your Code as below

```
body: ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: refreshPage,
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return MemesScreen(subreddits: subs);
      }),
     ......
```

Dialog page setState will be

```
  setState(() {
              subs = newSubs;
              refreshPage.value == 0
                  ? refreshPage.value = 1
                  : refreshPage.value = 0;
            });
```

globals.dart will be

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

String subs = 'meme';
final refreshPage = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
```

Check this full code working and tested:
main.dart

```
import 'package:answer_project/globals.dart';
import 'package:answer_project/meme_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(const MaterialApp(
 debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
 home: HomePage(),
 ));
 }

 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
   State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
  }

  class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final TextEditingController textEditingController = 
  TextEditingController();
  //String subs = "memes";

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor:
      const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 254, 241), //Color(0xffdedede),

  appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text("Memes"), backgroundColor: const 
  Color(0xff008b00)),

  body: ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: refreshPage,
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return MemesScreen(subreddits: subs);
      }),

  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
    backgroundColor: const Color(0xff008b00),
    onPressed: () {
      _showDialog();
    },
  ),
  );
  }

  void _showDialog() {
  showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    // return object of type Dialog
    return AlertDialog(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 254, 241),
      title: const Text("Enter subreddits"),
      content: TextField(
        controller: textEditingController,
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
        TextButton(
          child: const Text("Close",
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff008b00))),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),

        TextButton(
          child:
              const Text("Get", style: TextStyle(color: 
         Color(0xff008b00))),
          onPressed: () {
            String newSubs = textEditingController.text;
            setState(() {
              subs = newSubs;
              refreshPage.value == 0
                  ? refreshPage.value = 1
                  : refreshPage.value = 0;
            });
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
  );
   }
  }
```

meme_screen.dart

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MemesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
const MemesScreen({Key? key, required this.subreddits}) : super(key: 
key);
final String subreddits;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Card(
  child: Text(
    subreddits,
  ),
);
}
}
```

globals.dart

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  String subs = 'meme';

  final refreshPage = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
```

Another method of refreshing page is:
use Navigator.pushReplacement() instead of Navigator.of(context).pop().

This is the code of _showDialog():

```
void _showDialog() {
showDialog(
 context: context,
 builder: (BuildContext context) {
 // return object of type Dialog
 return AlertDialog(
  backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 254, 241),
  title: const Text("Enter subreddits"),
  content: TextField(
    controller: textEditingController,
  ),
  actions: <Widget>[
    // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
    TextButton(
      child: const Text("Close",
          style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff008b00))),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
    ),

    TextButton(
      child:
          const Text("Get", style: TextStyle(color: 
     Color(0xff008b00))),
      onPressed: () {
        String newSubs = textEditingController.text;
        setState(() {
          subs = newSubs;
          refreshPage.value == 0
              ? refreshPage.value = 1
              : refreshPage.value = 0;
        });
        //Navigator.of(context).pop();
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
        (BuildContext context) => HomePage()));
      },
    ),
  ],
  );
 },
 );
  }
```

It will reload the HomePage. But the last stack was lost means you cannot go back on last page.

Comment: Hi, I did everything you have mentioned here, but it is still not working.

Comment: put newSubs = textEditinController.text and remove 'String subs = "memes" 'from homepage.

Comment: I did that too, it did not work, same result

Comment: I have edited my post. copy and paste in new project these three pages-main.dart , meme_screen.dart, globals.dart Then run the project The Value of page is refreshed by entering in dialog box textField.

Comment: Okay, thanks! will try that.

Comment: It is working like expected with your code, but with my code in MemesScreen(), it is not working. Please have a look at this, https://ideone.com/hOEGaH  the baseUrl in this code is "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/${subreddits}/50"